# Максимально лучшее качество отображения шрифтов в OpenGL

Tags: шрифты, opengl

Подскажите каким образом можно добиться максимально лучшего качества отображения шрифтов в `OpenGL`? Использовал `FTGL`, но они там или размыты (растровые) или рубленые (векторные). Нужны шрифты максимально четкие.

Comment: использовать свои растровые шрифты

Answer (score 2):

Путем многочисленных пересборок FTGL и FreeType получил четкий растровый шрифт с выключенным `FT_CONFIG_OPTION_SUBPIXEL_RENDERING`, но при генерировании шрифта включил флаг `FT_LOAD_FORCE_AUTOHINT`.